# Minimized iPhone Applications - Respond to Network/Bluetooth/GPS?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gps, wifi, 3g

Just wondering, when an app on the iPhone 3GS/4 is minimized, is it possible for it to maintain a network (3G/Wifi), GPS or Bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the standard "Fast Application Switching" mechanism where the application is suspended in the background, no.

It can be done by the "VoIP" type background API can listen to network events while in the background.

Comment: does this include bluetooth and gps?

Comment: I don't know. I would look into the iOS 4.0 multitasking APIs (I believe there are seven types of them) - and see which one(s) fits your need the best.

Comment: Look at "UIBackgroundModes" - as in here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22